# Poll a file for change?

Tags: clojure

It is often a pattern that I wish to poll a file for changes (when it was last written). When the file does change from its previous value, I wish to execute some function. Something of the form.

```
(poll-for-changes file-str on-change-fx current-value)
```

where

1. `file-str` is just a string that specifies the files location
2. `on-change-fx` is the function that should be called when the file at `file-str` changes. Let us say that the `on-change-fx` should take the File object pointing to `file-str` as a argument.
3. `current-value` the current value of the file in milliseconds. You might set to 0 to guarantee that this function will run at least once, or to the actual value to only run this function when you actually detect a change.

I would just like this function implemented in the clearest, most concise, Clojurist way possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to poll a directory or files and act on it, I think [`watchtower`](https://github.com/ibdknox/watchtower) is pretty good to look at.

Java 7 has a WatchService, which uses file system events to react to changes.  In this case, you don't poll at all, but block on a future file event.  I don't think there are any projects in Clojure that are out there leveraging that, although I spent some time toying with it to write a [small library](https://github.com/klauern/java-watcher.clj).  The source for it [is here](https://github.com/klauern/java-watcher.clj/blob/master/src/com/klauer/java_watcher/core.clj)

I don't claim my library is even complete, but it does use the Java 7 service, so you could use that for inspiration on your own project.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches you could use here:

1. Use Java interop and [the Java 7 `WatchService` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).
2. Inspect and learn from [existing idiomatic, concise code](https://github.com/stuartsierra/lazytest/blob/master/modules/lazytest/src/main/clojure/lazytest/watch.clj) (in this case by Stuart Sierra) that does something like you want. Note it also uses Java Interop.

I think option #1 is your best bet, and the implementation of the function should be straight forward. You will likely want to use `doto` and the `->` and `->>` macros to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays I would probably try [`hara.io.watch`](http://docs.caudate.me/hara/hara-io-watch.html) first.

Otherwise there are many alternatives (as stated in the `hara` docs) :

- [clojure-watch](https://github.com/derekchiang/Clojure-Watch)
- [dirwatch](https://github.com/juxt/dirwatch)
- [hawk](https://github.com/wkf/hawk)
- [watchtower](https://github.com/ibdknox/watchtower)
- [java-watcher](https://github.com/klauern/java-watcher.clj)
- [panoptic](https://github.com/xsc/panoptic)
- [ojo](https://github.com/rplevy/ojo)
- [filevents](https://github.com/Raynes/filevents)

And some code can be extracted from :

- [lein-midje](https://github.com/marick/lein-midje)
- [ns-tracker](https://github.com/weavejester/ns-tracker)
- [lazytest](https://github.com/stuartsierra/lazytest)

You could also do what `hara` does and wrap [java.nio.file.WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).