# How do you constantly monitor the contents of a file in clojure?

Tags: csv, clojure

I have an incanter dataset that I would like to re-load every time another processes changes the source csv file. In other words, the mydata_ incanter dataset should be current every time I look. How can I implement this in idiomatic clojure?

```
(use 'incanter.io)
(def mydata_ (read-csv "./changingfile.csv"))
```

At some point, another process changes changingfile.csv, how do make sure that mydata_ is updated automatically? This is a bit different from just adding a watch function to an existing data structure within clojure.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe idiomatic Clojure would have you using `refs`/`atoms` or `core.async` to pass _values_ between the two processes. If any of those isn't an an option, you should consider one of the answers presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945780/poll-a-file-for-change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nice library for watching the file system here: https://github.com/derekchiang/Clojure-Watch 
can be used to watch the csv and can set mydata_ as an atom, or whatever uses mydata can be kicked off from clojure-watches callback.